# CMD search for specific line in output

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to make a little progrmm in c# which runs commands in CMD.
Everything is fine and in the output of the command is a list with a lot of useless information. Exept one line. This line, I want to 'filter' out and only display this.
So is ther a way I can make this happen?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There probably is a way you can make it happen, but that is not by asking us, it is by research and testing. This site helps you to fix an issue with your submitted code, it does not walk you through how to design, structure and write that code. Please feel free to return to this site with an on topic question once you've written your code, thank you.

Comment: The rules of engagement specified at http://stackoverflow.com/help indicate that an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example) needs to be provided. There is no code in the question. It is difficult to discuss fixing code when there is no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just launch your program in commandline and add `| findstr "pattern"` after it.

By "pattern", I mean something you can use to find that line, e.g. if your program prints a list of cats (ocelot, puma, lion, tiger) and you want to see the lion, you punt `| findstr "lion"`. Don't forget that `findstr` is case sensitive, you might need the `/I` switch, like this: `| findstr /I "LION"`.

For more information, type `findstr /?` in your commandline.